# Clustering on evenly spaced grid points

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have a 50 by 50 grid of evenly spaced (x,y) points. Each of these points has a third scalar value. This can be visualized using a contourplot which I have added. I am interested in the regions indicated in by the red circles. These regions of low "Z-values" are what I want to extract from this data.

2D contour plot of 50 x 50 evenly spaced grid points:
[image: 2D contour plot of 50 x 50 evenly spaced grid points]

I want to do this by using clustering (machine learning), which can be lightning quick when applied correctly. The problem is, however, that the points are evenly spaced together and therefore the density of the entire dataset is equal everywhere.

I have tried using a DBSCAN algorithm with a custom distance metric which takes into account the Z values of each point. I have defined the distance between two points as follows:\

```python
def custom_distance(point1,point2):
    average_Z = (point1[2]+point2[2])/2
    distance = np.sqrt(np.square((point1[0]-point2[0])) + np.square((point1[1]-point2[1])))
    distance = distance * average_Z
    return distance
```

This essentially determines the Euclidean distance between two points and adds to it the average of the two Z values of both points. In the picture below I have tested this distance determination function applied in a DBSCAN algorithm. Each point in this 50 by 50 grid each has a Z value of 1, except for four clusters that I have randomly placed. These points each have a z value of 10. The algorithm is able to find the clusters in the data based on their z value as can be seen below.

DBSCAN clustering result using scalar value distance determination:
[image: DBSCAN clustering result using scalar value distance determination]

Positive about the results I tried to apply it to my actual data, only to be disappointed by the results. Since the x and y values of my data are very large, I have simply scaled them to be 0 to 49. The z values I have left untouched. The results of the clustering can be seen in the image below:

Clustering result on original data:
[image: Clustering result on original data]

This does not come close to what I want and what I was expecting. For some reason the clusters that are found are of rectangular shape and the light regions of low Z values that I am interested in are not extracted with this approach.

Is there any way I can make the DBSCAN algorithm work in this way? I suspect the reason that it is currently not working has something to do with the differences in scale of the x,y and z values. I am also open for tips or recommendations on other approaches on how to define and find the lighter regions in the data.

Comment: _"These regions of low "Z-values" are what I want to extract ..."_  Could you just threshold your data to eliminate unwanted _"Z-values"_ and then cluster?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes definitely, and this is what I had done in the first place. However, it feels like I am artificially creating the clusters if I simply put a threshold Z value. It would be much more powerful to have an algorithm able to find the clusters without filtering the data first